# How to split such a string?

Tags: android

I get a result like this

```
{PickupLocation=204, Jai nagar main road, Chandragandhi Nagar, Ponmeni, Madurai, Tamil Nadu 625016, DropLocation=204, Jai nagar main road, Chandragandhi Nagar, Ponmeni, Madurai, Tamil Nadu 625016, PickupLongitude=78.0928147163509, DropLongitude=78.0928147163509, PickupLatitude=9.92065524221638, DropLatitude=9.92065524221638, CustomerId=99, PhoneNumber=96788484887, CustomerName=Mayil, CustomerLastName=Kannan}
```

i tried like this

```
 public static void jsonToMap(String t) throws JSONException {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String value = jObject.getString(key);
        map.put(key, value);

    }

    System.out.println("json : "+jObject);
    System.out.println("map : "+map);
}
```

But they don't give json format,but i want split to get the values separately,how is it possible,sorry for my poor english,i am beginner of the android.

Comment: It's not in JSON format. Ask your backend team to give you the response in the proper format.

Comment: there are no more option to split without helping backend?

Comment: It's not consistent data. There is no proper format. Half of them are in key-value pair and half of them are just value. You can try dirty trick to extract the value by splitting them with comma then check extracted string contains `=` again split them with `=`

Answer (score 1):

Not all values in the CSV list have equals sign, and hence a map may not make complete sense to store your values.  In the code snippet below I store values without an equals sign as a key in the map with no corresponding value.  You can strip the brackets on either end, split by comma and whitespace, then possibly split again by `=` to obtain the map you have in mind:

```
String input = "...";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
input = input.replaceAll("\\s+\\{\\s+(.*)\\s+\\}\\s+", "$1");
String[] parts = input.split(",\\s+");
for (String part : parts) {
    String[] vals = part.split("=");
    map.put(vals[0], vals.length > 1 ? vals[1] : null);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + ", value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not a valid Json. IMHO you should:

1. split the string on commas
2. for each substring, split by `=`
3. If you have an `=` then you have a key/value pair to add to the dict
4. If not, then you could build an array in a default key.